# Benefit of using ADF Model Layer when there is no Data base

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, model-view-controller, oracle-adf

I am making an application with Oracle ADF and the application has no Database to connect to. The Data store is a 3rd party application which i connect through web services.

The web service WSDL structure is complex in it self. after my workflow is completed, i need to post a response back to the 3rd party system via web service only.

My question here is that whether i need to use the ADF model layer as in fill VOs through Web service or expose Web Service as a Data Control.

I have read on this [blog](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2359508?start=0&tstart=0) a similar problem, but there is no final answer.

I have tried using AM method to populate the VOs programmtically, I have attempted to use web serivce as Data Control, I have also tried to base a View Object on a web service.

But what i dont get is why do i particularly need them..Why should i implement it all in ADF model layer and not get it over with in the Managed Bean layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, its better to have it in model layer just because of MVC pattern. You have view, you have bindings, you don't care where data comes from.

Now the real question, is what better to work with data in model layer:

1. Expose web service as data control directly. I think its a good
   choice if web service fairly simple and you don't need fast response
   from this actions.
2. Expose web service through POJO, is when your data too complex to work with web service directly. You free to do anything you want
   here, however you have very little support from adf side here,
   everything you want - you have to implement yourself. Its become
   really complex when you go to caching, load balancing and so on.
3. Istead of doing POJO DC, you can use populated programmaticaly view objects. And benefit from ADF VO support which can make use of
   this data much easer and robust. And you will have caching, scaling
   out of the box.

There is no silver bullet. Which method is better really depends on your needs. Sometimes you can just go with data control from your bean.